# Remove a watcher from my bitbucket project.

Tags: bitbucket

I have a private bitbucket repository for a side project. I invited someone to view it as part of an interview.

I have decided not to go any further with the interview. How do I remove this watcher?

Comment: I am also looking for this!  Currently, I have asked the guy to remove himself as watcher and removed any access from him, so I guess once he removes himself, he won't be able to come back, but this sounds silly to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it.

To remove a watcher from a repo, go to repo and click the settings cog (bottom left). 
Then access management on the left hand panel and you should get options there to remove them.

Another way to remove users from all repos is to go to your user settings (top right) -> manage account.
Then on the right go to "plans details" ans you have the option to remove users for all your repos.